Change selectCheckboxMenu behaviour
I have PrimeFaces tag selectCheckboxMenu.
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu dynamic="true"
                              filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith"
                              label="Cities"
                              style="width: 15rem" panelStyle="width: 15rem" scrollHeight="250"
                              value="#{checkboxView.selectedCities}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{checkboxView.cities}"/>

           
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>

I'm struggling to implement this:
When I open this list, so only top checkbox was checked, if no other checkbox is checked;
When I check one checkbox in list, then top checkbox unchecks;
I think js can help me and I tried to find smth in docs, but couldn't.

Please create a reproducer using https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Second part of your desired outcome is working as intended by default iirc. Regarding previous, if you want first item on list selected after you open the menu (if I understand correctly) use method toggleItem() and combine it with js function.
